# Why is the bench press harder than push ups and dips?

Tags: bench-press

So if you put yourself in a push up position on a digital balance it clearly tells you how much weight you are pushing.

Apparently on the top position with straight arms you are holding 61% of your total bodyweight on your palms.
On the bottom position with the chest touching the thumbs, what would be supposedly the bar touching the chest you are pushing 72% of your bodyweight.

And I can easily do push ups with another person standing on my **upper back** and I even tried weighted plates.

When calculating everything, I can easily push about 2.3 times more total weight with push ups than with a bench press.

With a bench press I struggle pushing my own bodyweight and my max is slightly above it by 10 kilograms.

I also tried dips, still I can output more pushing power when counting total weight.

I can actually dip with my one rep max bench press hanging off a dipping belt.

At first my first idea was that push ups are easier because you are anchored with 4 points, on your feet too.. But then what about dips? There's no anchor on dips, and most bench pressers arch their backs and use way more leg drive than it is used in a push up.

So why are push ups and dips considerably easier?

Comment: I would also argue that the bench press as also less range of motion because of the arching of the back, yet its still harder than full range push ups and dips

Comment: Did you do the scale experiment and weighted push-ups at the same time? Or separately and then added the additional weight to what you measured in an unweighted push-up? Due to leverage, you are not lifting 100% of the weight placed on your upper back in a push-up. Also, are you doing the pushups chest-to-ground?